# Существует ли для android аналог IE object?

Tags: android

В частности нажатие кнопок по id, получение ссылок на картинки. И какие бывают способы осуществления этих задач?

Answer (score 2):

В Android есть объект `WebView` (фактически виджет браузера), но его нутро (HTML объекты типа кнопки и проч.) недоступны стандартными способами. "Достучаться" до них можно только средствами JavaScript. Пример программного [нажимания HTML кнопки тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)